# Run a php script via Windows Batch File - not working in Task Scheduler only

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

My .bat files do not work with Task Scheduler.

For testing purposes, I created an extremely simple, one line .bat file:
php E:\POC\route.php

{the router.php file contain some file operation}
If I run this file by double-clicking it, it works correctly and Returned The Expected Output

But if I create a task to run this very same file, the text file is NOT created.  The History log for the task says that the task was started and completed successfully yet no text file is created.
 Note: Already i set the environment variable for php ("E:\Php")
Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `php` command with it's absolute path? Like `E:\Php\php.exe E:\POC\route.php`. Just to check if the environment variable is being correctly accessed by the user running the scheduled task.

Comment: i have tried with full path also.But its also not working through Scheduler . it works on when i manually double-clicking it . I think no issues present in .bat file. In Scheduler only its fail

Comment: Try it with your account permissions username/password and see if that works.  If it does then it's a permissions issue.  Also put `pause` after your command to see any error messages.  You may need to set task scheduler to interactive, so you can see the window.